# While Loop Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a while loop and I'm trying to delay it.

```
while (mode == 1)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(on) withObject:nil afterDelay:slider.value];
    NSLog(@"on");
    [self performSelector:@selector(off) withObject:nil afterDelay:slider.value];
    NSLog(@"off");
}
```

But even though I'm setting the slider to 10 seconds it goes on and off very fast.

Also my app black screens and I only see the status bar and my nslog but that might have to do with something else.

Comment: What is your end goal here? Change the value of your slider?

Comment: increase the value of time afterDelay:slider.value*2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does not wait for the selector to finish. This means that as soon as you are telling selector A to run after a certain time, it immediately goes on and tells selector B to run after a certain time. There are plenty of options to fix this:

If you would like to stick with selectors, you could use `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`. **Make sure you don't use the main thread though or you will experience UI freezes.**

`[NSThread waitForInterval]` is another option but, like the previous option, **will freeze the UI unless you are calling the entire while loop on a different thread**. I am surprised this has been mentioned so much without people noting this important factor.

GCD is another option. It doesn't wait for it to finish so you shouldn't experience major UI freezes.

```
dispatch_time_t dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, slider.value * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self on];
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self off];
    })
});
```

Another option is to keep what you are doing now and make selector B run after slider.value*2. If you think of this in a mathematically way, it makes sense:

```
A) 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
B) 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're telling your app:
"Turn on something in `slider.value` seconds from now"
"Turn off something in `slider.value` seconds from now"
Do you see a problem with that?

Comment: I have the function on and off set already but I didn't show it here since it's not related to the question.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Let's say the slider value is 2 seconds. You tell your app to call the `on` method in 2 seconds from now and the `off` method in 2 seconds from now. So `off` is called almost immediately after `on`.

Comment: Oh yeah now I get it, I must have read your comment a bit too fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
double delayInSeconds = slider.value;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self off];
    //or
    [self on];
});
```

This performs whatever inside the block after given time! :)

Answer (score 0):

The while loop doesn't wait for the delayed actions to complete, it simply schedules them. The problem is that you're scheduling all the events in a very quick loop that then runs the events one after the other just as quickly, all 10 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(on) withObject:nil afterDelay:slider.value];
```

In this statement afterDelay doesn't mean that it will pause for some second.

It means that method "on" will execute after some second. But execution will not wait to finish execution of method"on" and go to next statement.

If you want to make only some delay than you can use following statement :

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
```

This will wait for 2 second. But It may not be good idea because it will freeze your UI.

I hope this will help you.

All the best.....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn it on immediately and turn it off the specified delay:

```
[self on];
NSLog(@"on");
[self performSelector:@selector(off) withObject:nil afterDelay:slider.value];
NSLog(@"off");
```

If you want to turn it on after the specified delay, then turn it off again 10 seconds after that:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(on) withObject:nil afterDelay:slider.value];
NSLog(@"on");
[self performSelector:@selector(off) withObject:nil afterDelay:slider.value + 10];
NSLog(@"off");
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f]; it will stop your thread based on the time u are providing